# EF record Remove works on my computer, but not when published

Tags: sql, entity-framework, razor-pages

I have a Razor Pages app that I am design and then publishing.

When I run it on Server 2016 in IIS, I can add items to the database and update items in the database, but when I try to remove an item from the database, it gives me a 500 error.  I thought it was an issue with the specific code where I try to remove a record from the DB, but it does the same thing in other places.

On my computer, it works as it should.

Here is one of the examples:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteOrderLine(string subPO)
{
  string PON = "";

  if(subPO != null)
  {
    SteelOrderLine orderLine =
      _MCSContext
      .SteelOrderLines
      .First(sol => sol.SubPO.Equals(subPO));
    
    PON = _MCSContext
          .SteelOrders
          .First(so => so.ID == orderLine.SteelOrdersID)
          .PONumber;
                
    _MCSContext.SteelOrderLines.Remove(orderLine);
    await _MCSContext.SaveChangesAsync();

  }
            
  return RedirectToPage("CRUD", "EditLine", new { PONumber = PON });
}
```

Are there any settings in sql or in my Razor Pages project that might affect only Remove in the published project?

Comment: SQL has no settings. It's a language. Perhaps you mean dbms server settings.

Comment: A 500 error means an Exception is being thrown but it is not caught by your code so the asp.net code returns a status code 500. You need to debug your code or add logging to capture the Exception so you can better understand why the exception is being thrown. It could be a FK issue or permissions or schema not matching just to name some reasons (guessing really).

Comment: Yes, I mean dbms settings.  I will continue to dig for more information, but I am stumped for the moment on why it only fails on remove.  update and add work just fine, and everything works on my pc in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting from your example:

```
SteelOrderLine orderLine =
  _MCSContext
  .SteelOrderLines
  .First(sol => sol.SubPO.Equals(subPO));
```

if you expect one item back, use `Single` rather than `First`. First implies that if there are more than one match take the first one. This can conceal potential data issues / code assumptions, and cases where you legitimately expect more than one as a possibility you should always have an `OrderBy`(Descending) clause to ensure the selection is predictable & repeatable.

```
PON = _MCSContext
      .SteelOrders
      .First(so => so.ID == orderLine.SteelOrdersID)
      .PONumber;
```

For this line, you can bump performance by using:

```
PON = _MCSContext
      .SteelOrders
      .Where(so => so.ID == orderLine.SteelOrdersID)
      .Select(so => so.PONumber)
      .Single();
```

In your example you are loading the entire Steel Order entity just to get the PONumber. In the second example the SQL generated and executed will just return the PONumber. This can result in better performance (less memory use/processing to materialize tracked entities) If that column is indexed it can be a magnitudes faster query.